# What did I do wrong with my question when it was closed with "opinion-based" reason?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I wrote rather longer question regarding a problem I am facing. I abstracted the problem, described it, put as much information about it as I could think of.

I described what we have tried and we are trying right now. It is a technical problem on data modeling and I wanted an input from more knowledgeable people.

Here is the question: [Best (PostgreSQL? Couchbase?) data model and engine for querying entities with hundreds of attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135992/best-postgresql-couchbase-data-model-and-engine-for-querying-entities-with-h)

I do not understand, why it was closed? What could I have done better?

I am trying to lay out specific problem and I want to discuss best technology, data model and execution - all pretty fact based things.

Where did I go wrong, so I do not do the same thing again in the future?

Comment: Start with the title. "Best" is... not a useful thing to look for here.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, of course, now that you point it out, it is quite obvious. English is my second language, so it was not the elephant in room for me as it was for other people. Thank you, I will change it. Now that I see that, I realize how click-baitey it might look.

Comment: In principle (and w/o going into the details) - any question asking for the "best" anything is opinion-based, unless this "best" can be rigorously quantified (and measured). As a general rule of thumb, please keep in mind that there are questions that are perfectly valid in general, but still not a good fit for SO. In fact, being valid is a necessary but *not* a sufficient condition for a question to be on-topic here; the sufficient (extra...) condition is to conform to SO rules and guidelines, as they are explicitly described in the help system.

Comment: From a development standpoint, it doesn't really mean anything unless it's defined... but even then. on SO, questions shouldn't ask answers to create a list, or to provide what they think is best or what they prefer, even if you've defined a specific set of parameters that would make something best, at least at the "choose a framework/tool/thing" level. It's usually best for you to make that decision and then ask about something more specific.

Comment: Your other question literally starts with `I would like your opinion on ....`.  That question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62691185/best-postgresql-data-model-and-processing-for-incremental-entity-resolution-r should also be closed for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @JK.Should I change the title to something more appropriate, or close it? Because I got an answer I was looking for and I have a feeling that such a good approach might be beneficial to someone. On the other hand I do realize that leaving it like it is would give a wrong impression to other users how to ask the questions. Do you have any recommendation on what to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to me to be requesting recommendations in general for data models or SQL engines to run the kind of queries you are trying to run. Tool recommendation requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. The "best x for y" framing of the question in your title also did not help that consideration. That is why I voted to close it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, it is clear now. Next time I will have this in mind and frame the question correctly and focus more on the problems of solution we have already tried.

Answer (score 5):

While your question is dense and full of information, you're essentially looking to us for a benchmark to compare two DBs together.

We...don't provide those.  We can't provide those since they don't neatly fit in the context of Q&A.

You can't edit this question to make it "better" or more suited to the site, since...a question which asks *us* to benchmark two DB products isn't going to be on topic in any real context.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I see where I went wrong - I did not make clear enough that I am not looking for benchmark, I am capable and happy to do it myself. Instead, I am looking for a recommendation on how to design the dataset either as tables in relational database, or in JSON documents so it is easy for NoSQL DB to read. I was merely looking for a an data modeling approach I haven't tried yet, not any benchmark.

Comment: @VojtěchKurka I am afraid that such design recommendations are also off-topic here; [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *may* be an appropriate place for this.

Comment: I am going to head to help and guidelines section right now and not write anymore :)

Comment: @VojtěchKurka that's seldom a bad idea :) Remember, when we review posts, we always assume that OP's are already familiar with the rules and guidelines.

Comment: @VojtěchKurka "recommendation on how to design" A standard comment of mine says to follow an appropriate design method per a published academic textbook or other reference & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where first stuck; otherwise you are just asking us to (re)write such a reference. Plus most basic problems are already faqs, but to research them you have to phrase them clearly, concisely & generically--but that's another standard comment of mine. PS [Re EAV.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097)